# A.M.>G.M. of four numbers

Tags: inequality, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that arithmetic mean of $4$ numbers is greater than geometric mean of the same $4$ numbers, i.e.
prove that $$\dfrac{a+b+c+d}{4} > (abcd)^{\frac1{4}}$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: For correctness, I think you should add that a, b, c, d should all be different and non-negative.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** If you can use the AM-GM on 2 numbers, then you should use that.

First prove with this inequality on $(a,b)$ $$\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$$

Then prove with this inequality on $(c,d)$  $$\frac{c+d}{2} \geq \sqrt{cd}$$

Then use the AM-GM on 2 numbers again on the terms above.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality $\text{AM}>\text{GM}$ is equivalent to $\log\text{AM}>\log\text{GM}$, because the logarithm is a monotone increasing function.

Expanding $\log\text{AM}$ and $\log\text{GM}$,

\begin{align}
\log\text{AM} & = \log \frac{a+b+c+d}{4} \\
\log\text{GM} & = \log(abcd)^{1/4} = \frac{\log a+\log b+\log c+\log d}{4}
\end{align}

The result then follows because the logarithm is a [concave function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) (see [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality))

Comment: This is true by Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @wythagoras Thanks. I've included that

Comment: hi your method is interesing.

Comment: can u pls tell me what is concave function?

Comment: It's a function that lies above any of its [chords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)). It's the opposite of a convex function. Did you follow the link in my question?

Answer (score 1):

we have by AM-GM: $$\frac{\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{c+d}{2}}{2}\geq \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{2}\frac{c+d}{2}}\geq \sqrt{\sqrt{ab}\sqrt{cd}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**A very crude proof:**

We have the equation in L.H.S. as: $\dfrac{a+b+c+d}{4}$ and R.H.S. as $(abcd)^{1/4}$

Now shifting the $\dfrac{1}{4}^{th}$ power from r.h.s. to l.h.s., we get:

L.H.S. as $\bigg[\dfrac{a+b+c+d}{4}\bigg]^4$

$=\dfrac{a^4+4 a^3 b+4 a^3 c+4 a^3 d+6 a^2 b^2+12 a^2 b c+12 a^2 b d+6 a^2 c^2+12 a^2 c d+6 a^2 d^2+4 a b^3+12 a b^2 c+12 a b^2 d+12 a b c^2+24 a b c d+12 a b d^2+4 a c^3+12 a c^2 d+12 a c d^2+4 a d^3+b^4+4 b^3 c+4 b^3 d+6 b^2 c^2+12 b^2 c d+6 b^2 d^2+4 b c^3+12 b c^2 d+12 b c d^2+4 b d^3+c^4+4 c^3 d+6 c^2 d^2+4 c d^3+d^4 \color{blue}{+ 24abcd}}{4^4}$

which is clearly bigger than $abcd$ in the R.H.S.

Hope this satisfies!

Comment: I don't think your expansion is correct. You need to divide everything by $4^4$.

Comment: Sorry ... my bad!

Comment: $ 4^4 $ > 24, making the proof incorrect. Would have been a nice proof though!

Comment: Well you could make all kinds of horrible estimates (e.g $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4>4abcd$ by the rearrangement inequality) but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: @MonKeePoo yeh thats right... but if we shift $4^4=256$ to rhs...the lhs will still be huge!

Comment: Why is this clearly bigger than $abcd$? It could be the case that for example $4c^3d<0$.